# How to fill with values second nested array without replace the value

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, arraylist

I have the next problem

```
this.logs = {};

this.logs[1] = resp;
```

the result that I have in my first array is the next:
[image]

but when I add the second level array with the second array

```
this.logs[1][i] = resp;
```

The second array I inserted overwrites the string of the first array ... I don't know what to do with this case. I want the second level but without overwriting the string in the first array .....

[image: Screenshot]

I don't know what to do in this case...
I want the second level array without overwriting the first array string.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to concatenate two arrays? Do you want to add another array to `this.logs` OBJECT with the key 2?

Comment: I want a second level array or maybe its an object? I want to save the string name of first level array and add others values inside of that index. I'm doing a hard fail?

Comment: So you want to have this: `Stock maximo t = Stox maximo t-1 LA CANOJA` at the index 2 in logs array?

Comment: yes and same for index 1. its for double NgFor

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure if I understand what are you trying to achieve, especially that double `ngFor`. Below is how you can combine values from two arrays into a single one:

```
function combineTwoArrays() {
  let logs = [];

  const respOne = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
  const respTwo = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE'];

  logs = respOne.map((val, index) => { return val + ' ' + respTwo[index]});

  console.log('combine two arrays result:')
  console.log('logs:', logs)

  //combine two arrays result: 
  //logs: Array(5) [ "zero AAA", "one BBB", "two CCC", "three DDD", "four EEE" ]
}
```

See the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7cL0k1qd/

I hope I understood you if not, please explain a bit more what you mean by second level.